# Denied AWS Opensearch write permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-eks, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to connect a spring boot application from AWS EKS to AWS Opensearch both of which reside in a VPC. Though the connection is successful im unable to write any data to the index.

All the AWS resources - EKS and Opensearch are configured using terraform. I have mentioned the elasticsearch subnet CIDR in the egress which is attached to the application. Also, the application correctly assumes the EKS service account and the pod role - which I mentioned in the services stanza for Elasticsearch. In the policy which is attached to the pod role, I see all the permissions mentioned - ESHttpPost, ESHttpget, ESHttpPut, etc.

This is the error I get,

```
{"error":{"root_cause": [{"type":"security_exception", "reason":"no 
permissions for [indices:data/write/index] and User 
[name=arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NO:role/helloworld-demo-eks-PodRle- 
hellodemo-role-1,backend_roles= 
[arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NO:role/helloworld-demo-eks-PodRle-hellodemo 
role-1], requested 
Tenant=null]"}],"type":"security_exception", "reason":"no 
permissions for [indices:data/write/index] and User 
[name=arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NO:role/helloworld demo-eks-PodRle- 
hellodemo-role-1,
backend_roles=[arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NO:role/helloworld-demo-eks- 
PodRle-hellodemo role-1], requested Tenant=null]"},"status":403}
```

Is there anything that I'm missing out on while configuring?

Comment: It seems like the IAM role is missing some permissions, have you tried giving it all Openseach permissions? If that works then you can narrow it down to the missing permission

Answer (score 0):

This error can be resolved by assigning the pod role to additional_roles key in the Elasticsearch terraform. This internally is taken care by AWS STS when it receives a request from EKS.